# How to get users username from group when both has_many memberships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So my models looks like this:

```
class Group
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, :through => :memberships
end

class Membership
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end

class User
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :groups, :through => :memberships
end
```

**My question is, how can I find a user who created group in view?** Cause when I am iterating like this, it doesnt work:

```
<= @groups.each do |group| =>
  (What now? I have group and want to know who was a creator. I cant just type simply group.membership.username
<= end =>
```

And I cant just type @groups.memberships.each do because I use another parameters like group title, image, etc.

Comment: try: `<%= group.users.pluck(:username) %>`

Comment: @7urkm3n That is weird, it prints out just  `[]`

Comment: probably, yr group doesnt have users

Comment: @7urkm3n Oh, I just rememberd, the user doesnt exist anymore. Is there a way how can I store the users username even if he doesnt exist? I mean something else than save his username when he creates group?

Comment: make your best friend `rails console` )))

Comment: @7urkm3n I dont know how can I replicate my problem in rails c :-( And I dont know why, but username prints like this: `["username"]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113235/discussion-between-7urkm3n-and-boomerange).